# Representing geographical points/polygons in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, google-maps, mapping, gis

I'm building a website in Django, and I want one of my datatypes to be a geographical polygon. I want to mark points on a map (say, in Google Maps) and then store the resulting polygon in the database. 
Is there any way to do it that will save me the work of typing all the longitudes and latitudes manually?

I guess I'm looking both for a geographical library for Python, and for a special website that will let me mark points on the map and save them in a standard format.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're lucky, Django has maybe the best GIS support of all web frameworks:

[GeoDjango](http://geodjango.org/)

Comment: You will need support in the the database. PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle and SQLite should work, though.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I'm trying to figure out how to make it work on Windows, as most tutorials are written for Linux...

Comment: @Cornflake: what's wrong with http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#windows ?